# Rails 3 JQuery page.insert_html and TypeError: Element.insert is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I replaced Prototype with JQuery for Rails 3.
I am now trying to do the following:

```
  #photo
    =render 'shared/photo'
  = link_to_function "Add a Photo" do |page| |
      page.insert_html :bottom, 'photo', :partial => 'shared/photo', :object => Photo.new |
    end |
```

So the Javascript generated is:

```
try {
    Element.insert("photo", {
        bottom: "Data\n\n"
    });
} catch (e) {
    alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString());
    alert('Element.insert(\"photo\", { bottom: \"Data\\n\\n\" });');
    throw e
};
return false;
```

In the rails docs insert_html is a Prototype helper, but I thought that replacing Rails.js with the https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs would replace this helpers for JQuery helpers. I get a TypeError.ElementInsert is not a function.

Am I doing something wrong ? Or am I going to do this myself without the helpers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone just sent this question to me, maybe I can help. I'm on the jquery-ujs/jquery-rails team.

Unlike prototype-ujs for rails, jquery-ujs does not come bundled with rjs support. There is a separate gem that provides that functionality called [jrails](https://rubygems.org/gems/jrails).

[We've talked about merging the two projects](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails/issues/61), but decided to keep them separate, as it's more flexible that way.

Answer (score 2):

I have a fairly rudimentary workaround.
In my case I've run `page.insert_html(:top ,'content', render('form'))`.

The error is caused by the generated .js.rjs code trying to run Element.insert(), which is a prototype function. I don't know enough about rails to do anything very productive, however adding the following to my application.js has worked form me:

```
//Check if the function exists
if (typeof Element.insert !== "function") {
  //If not, hook it onto the $().append method.
  Element.insert = function (elem, ins) {
    $("#" + elem).append(ins.top);
  };
}
```

Obviously, this is basic and will only work with :top, so adjust to your needs. There must be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

yes rails.js is a js driver that js do callbacks on elements with
a data- attribute in the dom. (js submit, ajax links, etc)

what you need is a redefinition of prototype rails helpers which you cannot
expect from a js file unless it reimplements protptype syntax a la kdoole.

[this fork of jrails](https://github.com/theworkinggroup/jrails) provides what you need and works with rails 3

however it does not work with jquery for me. 
i searched for uptodate ones but found nothing.

UPDATE: i did manage to make it work smoothly, my fault...

i figured most people use js.erb templates with jquery which is likely the ugliest code format i
have ever seen.